# "Invalid_grant" Error When Using Passport and Google SSO on Production Server

Tags: laravel, rest, single-sign-on, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I'm facing a challenging issue while trying to implement Google SSO with Laravel using Passport. Everything works fine in the development environment and on the dev server, but when I attempt it on the production side, I encounter the following error:

```
Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I am confident that my code is correct since it runs smoothly in the development environment. Has anyone experienced a similar problem or can provide insights into the possible causes of this error?

Some additional information:

- I am using Passport for authentication.
- The issue only arises in the production environment, while everything functions normally in the development environment.
- I have already checked the configuration of my Google OAuth client, and everything seems to be correct.

I greatly appreciate any help and time you can provide. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Google Project for your live env as well, see https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/

You will also need to set up the proper credentials, such as Client ID and Secret. If this is properly set for your dev env, but not for your live env, then this is a major problem already.

If you ensure that you have everything properly set, then you will also need to compare the request that is being sent from your dev env and the request that is being sent from your live env and see whether there are differences in terms of request and response headers and/or payload.